# javascript retrieve fetch response from a php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm try to implement the paypal express checkout.
So I implement the button and write the result in my database. Nothing exceptional, it's the script they gave.

```
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('recordDatabase.php', {
          method: 'post',
          mode: "same-origin",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: JSON.stringify({
              orderID: data.orderID, 
              time: details.create_time, 
              status: details.status, 
              nom: details.payer.name.given_name, 
              prenom: details.payer.name.surname, 
              pays: details.payer.address.country_code, 
              valeur:details.purchase_units[0].amount.value
          })
        })
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

The php to record in the database:

```
<?php
$link = connect();

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//Receive the RAW post data.
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ?trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

if ($contentType === "application/json") {
    //Receive the RAW post data.
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

    //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
    if(! is_array($decoded)) {
        //echo "error";
    } else {
        $name = $decoded['nom'];
        $time = $decoded['time'];
        $id = $decoded['orderID'];
        $stat = $decoded['status'];
        $pays = $decoded['pays'];
        $val = $decoded['valeur'];

        $secQuery = "INSERT INTO myDatabase(PSEUDO,PASSWORD,CONNECTION,INSCRIPTION,ANNIVERSAIRE,MAIL,IDPAYPAL,STATPAYPAL,NOMPAYER,PAYS,VALEUR) VALUES ('essai','123456',0,'$date','$time','email@mail','$id','$stat','$name','$pays','$val') ";
        if (mysqli_query($link,$secQuery)) {
            //echo "ok";
        } else {
            //echo "error";
        }

    }
} else {
    //echo "error";
}
```

So, the record in my database works fine, but my question is:

How can I retrieve the echo error or ok in the javascript to confirm the user that everything is fine, or if an error happen.

I tried another solution, to redirect the user from the php and add to the php:

`header("Location: confirmation web page");` or
`echo "<script>window.location = 'confirmation web page'</script>";`

but both solution doesn't work. No redirection happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct if i'm wrong, `recordDatabase.php` is your php file that is storing the transactions.

So, the `return fetch('recordDatabase.php', {` is returning the response from this file, your `echo 'ok';`,`echo 'error';`, the fetch is asyncronous, so it'will return a promise.

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to your php file so it returns a json response.
Also change your echo to `echo '{"status":"ok"}';` and `echo '{"status":"error"}';`

Now modify your fetch function,

```
return fetch('recordDatabase.php', {
     //same info here
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
      if(responseData.status == "ok"){
           alert("it worked");
      }else{
           alert("it didn't work");
      }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the `response.json()` and `responseData.status == "ok"` idea, Now I'm using `response.text()` and `response.includes('<response form text to find>')` for my contact form that's `post`ing to the same page on `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved your case , just try this code and see how it works
Paypal Script API

```
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name+' ApplicationId <?php echo $id; ?> :payerID'+data.payerID);

        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('payments.php', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              orderID: data.orderID, 
              time: details.create_time, 
              status: details.status, 
              nom: details.payer.name.given_name, 
              prenom: details.payer.name.surname, 
              pays: details.payer.address.country_code, 
              valeur:details.purchase_units[0].amount.value
          })
        }).then(data => data.ok && data.json()).then(response => {
            alert(response.status);
        });         
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**PHP script (payments.php)**

```
 <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //Receive the RAW post data.
    $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ?trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

    if ($contentType === "application/json") {
        //Receive the RAW post data.
        $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

        //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
        if(! is_array($decoded)) {
            //echo "error";
        } else {
            $name = $decoded['nom'];
            $time = $decoded['time'];
            $id = $decoded['orderID'];
            $stat = $decoded['status'];
            $pays = $decoded['pays'];
            $val = $decoded['valeur'];

          echo '{"status":"ok"}';

        }
    } else {
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

`return fetch('codes/paypalapi.php', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID
          })

        });`

it will work perfectly 
i had the same situation

Comment: Adding headers: {  'content-type': 'application/json' } will break the whole uploading process